# Apache Custom error message 403

Tags: apache2, webserver, apache2.4

i wanna to create a custom error message in Apache conf for the `Error message 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server` to appear like `404 Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server`.
Is this possible to do with Apache? Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have permission to write /etc/apache directory?

Comment: Take a look at the apache ErrorDocument directive.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. Ofc i do @Tohid Tamboli, i crate special folder with sensitive files and i want the forbidden access to apeared like custom error 404, file not found... I have read it Soren A  and didnt find how to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

edit the AllowOverride feature to ALL

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

You need access to .htaccess.

```
ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry you are late Session Time out!!!"

ErrorDocument 403 /xyz/yxz/error.html
```

Comment: Tried out and doesnt working, i still got status code 403 returned by browser. Thx btw.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

From the [htaccess site](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/):

> **.htaccess** is a configuration file for use on web servers running the
>   Apache Web Server software. When a .htaccess file is placed in a
>   directory which is in turn 'loaded via the Apache Web Server', then
>   the .htaccess file is detected and executed by the Apache Web Server
>   software. These .htaccess files can be used to alter the configuration 
>   of the Apache Web Server software to enable/disable additional
>   functionality and features that the Apache Web Server software has to
>   offer. These facilities include basic redirect functionality, for
>   instance if a 404 file not found error occurs, or for more advanced
>   functions such as content password protection or image hot link
>   prevention.

To set-up custom error documents, create a `.htaccess`:

```
echo "ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.html" > .htaccess
```

The above line tells the Apache Web Server to display the document located at `/error_pages/404.html` (under your domain name/web site address) whenever a 404 (file not found) error occurs.

It is **assumed** you have created the error document and called it  `404.html`  and that you have placed it in a directory called  `error_pages`  under your domain name. For example, `http://www.yourdomain.com/error_pages/404.html`

The document `404.html` is a normal HTML document like the others in your web site and can display whatever content you wish, however it is useful to include a  'File Not Found' message.

To setup further error documents, for example for '401 Unauthorised', '403 Forbidden', and '500 Internal Server' error messages, create a `.htaccess file` following the main instructions and guidance which includes the following text:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error_pages/401.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error_pages/500.html
```

Comment: I didnt use htaccess, i used only apache config file, i follow the tutorial on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04.And error msg works only on VB machine where i use port 80 and no SSL, but when i apply them to my server(SSL and port 443) it doesnt work i got this message "Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.I put a file in /var/www/html and ErrorDocument in apache conf . Any idea ??

Comment: You have to create an `.htaccess` in your domain directory. You should redit your post to add the info (tutorial you followed) of the comment above. Did you `sudo apache2ctl configtest` and `sudo service apache2 restart`?

Comment: Is there any way to do it without .htaccess ? Cause when i had .htacess in my prevoius server it slow down apache so much, and it causes me even some crashes. I would like to avoid htaccess at any cost. Thanks your reply btw i really appreciate that

Comment: yes, as described in your tutorial. Reedit your post and post `sudo apache2ctl configtest`

Comment: I tried .htaccess and doesnt give me resulsts. Thx for post btw